# Nested JSON not display in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm having trouble accessing the nested JSON using the ng-repeat directives.  I know it is working because the not nested part of the JSON object is displaying.

Here is a plunker of my code: http://plnkr.co/edit/V2iURMa8t7vG9AqDFMOf?p=preview

JavaScript:

```
var app = angular.module("app", [ ]);
app.controller("AppTest", function($scope){
$scope.currentInfo=[{"id":0,"article":"JavaScript Conquers the World","publisher":"Daily Times","meta_data":{"comments":4}},
  {"id":1,"article":"The Problem with Foobar","publisher":"New York Times","meta_data":{"comments":27}}];
$scope.tableInfo=[{"name":"id","dataType":"Integer","isEditable":false},
  {"name":"article","dataType":"String","isEditable":true},
  {"name":"publisher","dataType":"String","isEditable":false},
  {"name":"meta_data.comments","dataType":"Integer","isEditable":false}];
});
```

HTML:

```
 <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="AppTest as app"
  <table>
    <tbody ng-repeat="anotherItem in currentInfo">
      <tr>
        <td ng-repeat="item in tableInfo">{{anotherItem[item.name]}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
 </body>
```

Comment: You can't do that, basically you're asking for 

anotherItem["meta_data.comments"] which is not the same as anotherItem["meta_data"]["comments"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution that is better is to add function in the controller that will resolve the value for you.  The issue with your solution is that you need Angular to resolve meta_data.comments, but it is treating it as the string that is used in the array lookup since it has already resolved item.name.

```
$scope.resolveLookup = function(object, lookup) {
    var depth = lookup.split('.').length;
    var currentObj = object;

    for(var x=0; x<depth; x++) {
      currentObj = currentObj[lookup.split('.')[x]];
    }
    return currentObj;
};
```

Then change the HTML to look like:

```
<td ng-repeat="item in tableInfo">{{resolveLookup(anotherItem,item.name)}}</td>
```

Here is the Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/RVd2ncwstyQtCtdhcC9U?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that it is putting 'metadata.comments' in the [] and it doesn't realize that it needs to be resolved again by angular.  I can't think of fix without changing the data structure of your 'tableInfo' object.

Here is how I would do it.

Change table info to:

```
 $scope.tableInfo = [{
    "name": ["id"],
    "dataType": "Integer",
    "isEditable": false
  }, {
    "name": ["article"],
    "dataType": "String",
    "isEditable": true
  }, {
    "name": ["publisher"],
    "dataType": "String",
    "isEditable": false
  }, {
    "name": ["meta_data", "comments"],
    "dataType": "Integer",
    "isEditable": false
  }];
```

Change your HTML to:

```
      <td ng-repeat="item in tableInfo" ng-if="item.name.length==1">{{anotherItem[item.name[0]]}}</td>
      <td ng-repeat="item in tableInfo" ng-if="item.name.length==2">{{anotherItem[item.name[0]][item.name[1]]}}</td>
```

Here is the Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/q9lHZ2TD7WZ74b2f6Ais?p=preview